# Can you select the index of a row from a query?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to use `QUERY` and select the index of a row instead of specific cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear exactly what you are trying to do, but this will create a query column of row numbers. You can then query a value and return the row or query the row number and return a value.

```
=query({A2:B, arrayformula(row(A2:B))}, "select Col1, Col3 where Col3 = 3")
```

Comment: I was not aware of the `ROW` function. In the first argument for `QUERY`, you are creating a set, correct? But when doing so, you can only access the columns using "Col`X`" syntax rather than letters?

Comment: That is correct. The column must be referenced. The is no data in C of the sheet.

Comment: Thank you. I was having difficulty even knowing what to ask, but your answer has told me everything I need to know!